# Missing stylesheets in production-environment?

Tags: css, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, dev-to-production

I am experiencing inconsistent styling between environments after pushing an update to my production server. My development machine runs Mongrel with SQLite, while my production server runs Passenger with MySQL.

In development, the styling renders as expected. In production, everything is messed up. Divs are clipping content, for example. A certain page added with the update is accessible in development but not accessible in production, despite both environments having the same code. I checked the server log files, but nothing 'weird' is shown.

To summarize, everything works as expected in development. In production, styles are messed up and a page is inaccessible.

What am I missing?

Comment: By default you need to run the precompile command on your server to generate the CSS files. On your *DE* this works *on the fly*, but by default not so on *PE*. I know this is very basic, but you haven't said nothing about this.

Comment: Thank you, this could be basic. Guess I missed it. After I ran `rake assets:precompile` it sure did some good to my styling! Only, now all graphs are 'blown up'. Like, really big! Not like my DE.  But thank you again, I missed that command.

Comment: it can also be possible if you have to main different css files (eg application.css and landing.css), then you need to set it additionally in your production.rb:
`config.assets.precompile += %w( landing.css )`

http://guides.rubyonrails.org/asset_pipeline.html#precompiling-assets

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion. I will have a look tomorrow. Keep you posted.

Comment: It worked! It even fixed the 'broken' page!  Thank you @pzin and Betty St